# What will happen if I include vhost config file directly in "sites-enabled" folder?

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I am currently studying Apache virtual hosts and have some confusion regarding their configuration.

I have created a virtual host file in the `sites-available` folder and enabled the corresponding site using the command `a2ensite example.com.conf`  as root. I notice when doing so that this creates a symlink in the `sites-enabled` folder.

To more thoroughly understand the behaviour, I experimented by saving the `example.com.conf` file directly into the `sites-enabled`, eschewing the indirection via a symlink. After restarting Apache, I was surprised to find the virtual host continues to work fine.

If I store `example.com.conf` file only in `sites-enabled`, without storing in `sites-available` folder and using a symlink, will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This folder structure is all about manageability. While it would be perfectly fine to add all module and virtual host configuration into a single `httpd.conf`, it would make it long and tricky to modify. Therefore, for example in Debian, wildcard includes have been used to separate the configuration into multiple files:

```
# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

This makes everything matching path `sites-enabled/*.conf` to be added to the configuration, and for the Apache HTTPd it doesn't matter whether it's a text file or a symlink to one. From this perspective, it doesn't even matter whether the file has `<VirtualHost>` blocks in it or is just some other Apache configuration. It's also perfectly possible to have file `example.com.conf` with configuration for `example.net` etc.

The problems you will face with unconventional configuration are related to the lack of manageability:

- You won't be able to enable or disable virtual hosts with `a2ensite` / `a2dissite`.

  ```
  # a2dissite example.com
  ERROR: Site example.com does not exist!
  ```

  - The official documentation (man pages) becomes useless.
  - You can't easily temporarily disable the site. E.g. a catch-all virtual host makes it easy to create an *under maintenance* page to show while the site is disabled for updates.
- Someone else administering the same server may have used to use `ln -s` and `rm` instead of these official commands. While trying to temporarily disable the site, they might accidentally delete it.
- No-one else knows you haven't been following the normal practices. In a few months you will forget it, too. At that point you will ask a new question on Serverfault regarding why following the documentation or a tutorial doesn't apply for your setup anymore.